# EntityType 'Products' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have created a model class

```
namespace EcommerceApplication.Models
{
    public class Products
    {
        [Key]
        [Required]
        public int ProductID;
        public string ProductName;
        public decimal Price;
        public string ProductImage;
    }
}
```

I also have added `Key` attribute to my id but its still showing

`EntityType 'Products' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.`

this is my controller code where I am using it

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        DbClass _db = new DbClass();
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var products=_db.products.ToList();
            return View(products);
        }

    }
```

my DbClass as follow

```
 public class DbClass:DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Products> products { get; set; }
    }
```

what wrong in this code .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your variables to a property, e.g.:

```
public int ProductID { get; set; }
```

Comment: Oh Dumb Enough .. Thank you very much .

Comment: It happens all the time, you are welcome! It might make sense to make all your public variables to properties.